# One example Point mass at zero

Tags: calculus, probability, stochastic-processes

I am learning the discrete random variable. We say $X$ a discrete random variable if for a countable subset $B\subset \mathbb{R}$,
$$P(X\in B)=1.$$

One example: If $F(x)=1$ for $x\ge 0$, $F(x)=0$ for $x<0$. Why this distribution is asscotied with a discrete r.v.?

Comment: To be clear, is $F$ a *cumulative* distribution function?  It had better be.  It follows from the definitions that this distribution corresponds to $\Pr(X=0)=1$ and $\Pr(X\neq 0)=0$.  Our $B$ here is precisely $\{0\}$.  That is to say, our random variable is always equal to $0$.

Comment: Do not confuse cumulative distribution functions with probability distribution functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x)=1$ for all $x\geqslant 0$ means that $F(x)=\Pr [X\leqslant x]=1$ if $\geqslant 0$ and $\Pr [X\leqslant x]=0$ if $x<0$, so

$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr [X=x]&=\Pr [X\leqslant x]-\Pr [X<x]\\
&=\Pr [X\leqslant x]-\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pr [X\leqslant x-1/n]\\
&=F(x)-\lim_{n\to\infty}F(x-1/n)
\end{align*}\\[1em]
\therefore\quad  \Pr [X=x]=1\iff x=0
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am confused about the $\lim F(x-1/n)$. We know $F$ is right-continuous. But it seems that the limit of $\lim F(x-1/n)$ is a left one. How to compute this limit?

Comment: if $x\leqslant 0$ then $F(x-1/n)=0$ for all $n$, therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}F(x-1/n)=0$. If $x>0$ by the same reasoning we find that $\lim_{n\to\infty}F(x-1/n)=1$, where the result follows